# Simple script in blade to show different components

Tags: javascript, laravel

I haven't used Laravel in ages and I'd like to show different blade components on different clicks. In `gridFirst` I'd like the user to choose an option, one of the items with `class="firstgridItem"`. Can someone explain me the basics on how to implement clicks like this to render specific components? Maybe that way I'll also learn how to/why not to implement my own Javascript options/variables/methods etc., because atm I have no idea on where to store or how to access them?

```
<section class="grid">
    <div class="gridFirst">
        <h1 class="gridTitle">VIPDECK</h1>
        <div>
            <div class="firstgridItem" id="koppelen-link">
                <p>BRIL KOPPELEN</p>
                <p>></p>
            </div>
            <div class="firstgridItem" id="bestellingen-link">
                <p>OVERZICHT BESTELLINGEN</p>
                <p>></p>
            </div>
            <div class="firstgridItem" id="klanten-link">
                <p>OVERZICHT KLANTEN</p>
                <p>></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gridMid">
        @if ("koppelen"==="koppelen")
            <x-klanten-brillen />
        @elseif (2===2)
            <x-bestellingen-overzicht />
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="gridLast">
        @if (2===1)
            <x-klanten-brillen />
        @elseif (2===2)
            <x-bestellingen-overzicht />
        @endif
    </div>
</section>
```

I've played around with the if-statements in `gridMid` for a bit and I can get them to show different components, just not on a different (Javascript?) variable.

Comment: Laravel's view components do not offer that sort of dynamic behavior. Clicking or calling methods in the component do not trigger re-renders.

The [`livewire/livewire`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart) package offers that sort of behavior by extending laravel's view compoments.

Comment: I can't understand your problem. Do you want to use JS or not?

Comment: @EHFShahab Yes I would like to, just don't know how to

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand how 2 === 1 or why check that 2 === 2 but this example shows how to append things to a div. If you have select with options and didn't mention in your question please add it and let me know to add example for select or retrieving data as json from controller.

```
<section class="grid">
        <div class="gridFirst">
            <h1 class="gridTitle">VIPDECK</h1>
            <div>
                <div class="firstgridItem" id="koppelen-link">
                    <p>BRIL KOPPELEN</p>
                    <p>></p>
                </div>
                <div class="firstgridItem" id="bestellingen-link">
                    <p>OVERZICHT BESTELLINGEN</p>
                    <p>></p>
                </div>
                <div class="firstgridItem" id="klanten-link">
                    <p>OVERZICHT KLANTEN</p>
                    <p>></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gridMid" id="mid"></div>
        <div class="gridLast" id="last"></div>
    </section>
    
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () { 
                 let koppelen = "koppelen";
                 
                 if(koppelen === "koppelen")
                 {
                  $("#mid").append('<x-klanten-brillen />');
                  } else if(2 === 2)
                  {
                  $("#mid").append('<x-bestellingen-overzicht />');
                  $("#last").append('<x-bestellingen-overzicht />');
                  } else if(2 === 1)
                  {
                  $("#last").append('<x-klanten-brillen />');
                  }           
             });
    </script>
```